# How can i get prefix pf phone number?

Tags: iphone, ios, regex, phone-number

Hello everyone I am trying to get prefix of phone numbers in order to get the actual phone number without country dialing code. How can I achieve this?

Please note that the phone numbers can be

> 123456789
>   0099123456789
>   +9912345678

or any other formats with country code and area code etc..

Comment: Please show us your own attempt.

Comment: every phone number having 10 digits except country code?

Comment: i was trying to use a subindex.. but no the number phone varies

Comment: Did you solve it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

if you tried like this then it will help some what but not sure ,

```
NSString *str=[PhoneNumber substringToIndex:[PhoneNumber length]-10];
```

Comment: in that case we can't do anything .if is there any separator or anything else then ok otherwise we can't get.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the amount of different prefixes you can have [List of country calling codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes) [wikipedia] and [Internatioal dialing prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internatioal_dialing_prefix) [wikipedia], one could reach the conclusion that without narrowing the area down you'll probably not get very far with this.

If however you'll be handling phone numbers from a specific region to another specific region you might be able to come up with something.